# How to set Serenity tag

Tags: discussion

I want to ask about Serenity framework but it is not available in tag list. Without tag I cannot track my questions.

[Serenity MVC Framework](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/559ec6fc-feef-4077-b6d5-5a99408a6681)